# I have a problem that text of button disapperred after on click how can I fix the text after clicking

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a problem that the text of the button disappeared after on click. How can I fix the button after clicking on it?

In xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:onClick="message6"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle373"
    android:text="Apply"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView10"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView8"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />
```

and the Java code:

```
public void  message6(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent( Choosetopics.this, biggertopic.class);
    Button Button20 = (Button ) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    Intent intent15 = getIntent();
    String message = intent15.getStringExtra( biggertopic.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    Button20.setText(message);
    startActivity ( intent );
}
```

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: probably when you get the intent you get nothing, see on this platform how to use properly the intent function

Comment: Please, next time if you post source code, format it properly in order to we can read it better.

Comment: thanks I deleted these two lines and it is worked properly                                                        Intent intent15 = getIntent();
    String message = intent15.getStringExtra( biggertopic.EXTRA_MESSAGE);